# Click on toggle open all the divs, how to avoid it?

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I have a toggle for social sharing inside the article but when I click on it, it opens in all the articles.

I tried to do something in the css, but I think the problem is in the jquery.

```
$(document).ready (function(){
$(".social-box").click(function(){
$(".a").toggleClass("active");
});
$(".social-box").click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass("activered");
```

I expect it opens only in the article selected.

Edited:

```
<div id="post"><div class="social-box"><h5><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></h5> 
         <div class="a"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></div>
            <div class="a"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></div>
            <div class="a"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></div>
            <div class="a"><i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i></div>
        </div> <p></p></div>
```

Comment: And HTML markup? You have to fire just one of all `div`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are targeting all of your `class="a"` elements instead of the ones contained within the selected `.social-box`. You will need to target only those elements within.

```
$(document).ready (function(){
  $(".social-box").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".a").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("activered"); 
  });
});
```